# Modo verbal después de "no porque"

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis

> *Fumaba siempre a escondidas, no sólo porque era mal visto **que una
>   mujer fumara en público**, sino porque a ella le gustaba fumar sola.*

Dos preguntas:

1. Tengo una duda respecto a tipo de oración subordinada: ¿Es el fragmento en negrita una oración sustantiva (¿*qué es lo que era mal visto*?) o se refiere a la oración causal (*no sólo porque …, sino porque*)?
2. ¿Por qué la forma *era* está en indicativo? Como negamos la validez de la causa, debería ir en subjuntivo, ¿no?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: 2. ¿Hemos negado la validez de la causa? Solo hemos dicho que hay más razones adicionales y no que la razón dada está infundada. It just said that there were more reasons, not that the one given wasn't also true/valid.

Answer (score 2):

En tu ejemplo, *que una mujer fumara en público* es una subordinada sustantiva, como puede verse si la reemplazamos en el original:

> *Era mal visto **que una mujer fumara en público**.*
>
> ***Eso** era mal visto.*

La proposición *era mal visto* no está negada; lo que niega el *no* es la exclusividad del *sólo*. En la estructura *no sólo X sino Y*, tanto X como Y se entienden como afirmativas, y de hecho queda implícito que es *no sólo X sino **también** Y*.

Comment: De acuerdo.  Agrego: compara con esta frase: *Fumaba siempre a escondidas, no porque fuera mal visto que una mujer fumara en público, sino porque a ella le gustaba fumar sola.*